# Erlang list comprehension, permutations

Tags: erlang, list-comprehension

I was tinkering with a permutations example from a book. Following code works as intented.

```
perms([]) -> [[]];
perms(L) -> [[H|T] || H <- L, T <- perms(L--[H])].
```

And when I substitute the expressions it become this:

```
[ [1 | perms([2])], 
   [2 | perms([1])] ]

[ [1 | [[2 | perms([])]]], 
   [2 | [[1 | perms([])]]] ]

[ [1 | [ [2 | [[]] ] ]], 
  [2 | [ [1 | [[]] ] ]] ]
```

And this evaluates correctly to [[1,2], [2,1]].

But when I changed the base case to the empty list from a list contains an empty list:

```
perms([]) -> [];
```

It returns an empty list. When I substitute I got this.

```
   [ [1 | [[2 | [] ]]], 
     [2 | [[1 | [] ]]] ]
```

I tried both expression with flatten but they yielded same and correct result.

```
[[1 | lists:flatten([[2 | lists:flatten([[]]) ]])], [2 | lists:flatten([[1 | lists:flatten([[]]) ]])]]
[[1 | lists:flatten([[2 | lists:flatten([]) ]])], [2 | lists:flatten([[1 | lists:flatten([]) ]])]].
```

So I couldn't figure out the difference between two expressions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This function implements a recursive algorithm:

- What are the permutations of a non-empty list?  For each of the elements in the list, take the permutations of the list minus that element and prepend the element to each such permutation.
- What are the permutations of an empty list?  There is just one: the empty list itself, so we return a list containing one element, namely the empty list: `[[]]`

By changing the base case to return `[]` instead of `[[]]`, you're saying:

- What are the permutations of an empty list? There are zero permutations.

And then in the recursive case, you get to the step "take the permutations of..." - but there are no permutations, so there is nothing you can prepend elements to.